# progress bar freezes for few seconds and then grid view shows

Tags: android, gridview, progressdialog

ok im fetching images from server and showing them in a **gridview** with title ... im using **baseadapter** for gridview ... everything is working good and fine ... i have just one problem that i need to show a **progressdialog** when data is fetched from server and populated on the gridview ... 
im using **AsyncTask** right now for showing progress dialog but it freezes for few (like 10) seconds and then gridview shows...

this is my baseadapter class:

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    ViewHolder holder;
    if (convertView == null) {
        convertView = listInflater.inflate(R.layout.grid_adapter_view, null);
        holder = new ViewHolder();
        holder.gridImg = (ImageView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_image);
        holder.gridTitle = (TextView) convertView
                .findViewById(R.id.grid_item_label);
        convertView.setTag(holder);
    } else {
        holder = (ViewHolder) convertView.getTag();
    }
    holder.gridTitle.setText(catItems.get(position).getName());
    try {
        URL url = new URL(catItems.get(position).getImg());
        Bitmap img = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection()
                .getInputStream());
        holder.gridImg.setImageBitmap(img);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        holder.gridImg.setImageResource(R.drawable.no_image);
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return convertView;
}

public class ViewHolder {
    ImageView gridImg;
    TextView gridTitle;

}
```

and here is asynctask im using:

```
mytask = new AsyncTask<Void, Void, Boolean>() {

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Boolean result) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            super.onPostExecute(result);
            main_grid.setAdapter(adater);
            if (progress.isShowing()) {
                progress.dismiss();
            }

        }

        @Override
        protected void onPreExecute() {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            progress.show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Boolean doInBackground(Void... params) {
            JSONArray jArray = request.getCategories();
            try {
                for (int i = 0; i < jArray.length(); i++) {
                    CategoriesDetail catDetail = new CategoriesDetail();
                    JSONObject jobj = jArray.getJSONObject(i);
                    catDetail.setId(jobj.getString("id").toString());
                    catDetail.setName(jobj.getString("name").toString());
                    catDetail.setImg(jobj.getString("img").toString());
                    catDetail.setOrder(jobj.getString("order").toString());
                    items.add(catDetail);
                }
                adater = new CatGridAdapter(MainActivity.this, items);
                return true;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                progress.dismiss();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this,
                        "Error: " + e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG)
                        .show();
                return false;
            }

        }

    };
```

please tell me where and what im doing wrong ...

Comment: Show how you start your AsyncTask please.

Comment: just like **mytask.execute();**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing a network operation on the UI thread.

```
BitmapFactory.decodeStream(url.openConnection().getInputStream());
```

Take a look at this: http://developer.android.com/training/displaying-bitmaps/process-bitmap.html

**EDIT:**
Instead of decoding the stream in `getView()` only set the default image to the `gridImg` and trigger `loadBitmap(catItems.get(position).getImg(), holder.gridImg)`.

```
public void loadBitmap(String url, ImageView imageView) {
    new BitmapWorkerTask(imageView).execute(url);
}

class BitmapWorkerTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Bitmap> {
    private final WeakReference<ImageView> imageViewReference;

    public BitmapWorkerTask(ImageView imageView) {
        // Use a WeakReference to ensure the ImageView can be garbage collected
        imageViewReference = new WeakReference<ImageView>(imageView);
    }

    // Decode image in background.
    @Override
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... params) {
        return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(params[0].openConnection().getInputStream());
    }

    // Once complete, see if ImageView is still around and set bitmap.
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
        if (imageViewReference != null && bitmap != null) {
            final ImageView imageView = imageViewReference.get();
            if (imageView != null) {
                imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is all described in the link above. You should really read it to get a better understanding of threading in android.

Comment: but im declaring grid view adapter in asynctask
**adater = new CatGridAdapter(MainActivity.this, items);**
so should i create another asynctask in baseadpater for decoding stream ??

Comment: It doesn't matter where the adapter is created, the getView() method is invoked in the UI-thread. I updated my answer with a possible solution to your problem.

Comment: thanks man .. now i got it never use getView in the main UI-thread... thanks once again :)

Comment: It's okay to set simple view values in `getView()`, but try to avoid using the `BitmapFactory`s `decode*()` methods in the UI-thread.

Comment: even if im decoding any Bitmap from app's resources ??

Comment: If you decoding a small resource it should be okay, depends on the overall memory usage, view count and resource size. But using views with adapers, like `GridView` or `ListView`, I would highly recommend using multiple threads for loading `Bitmap`s.
And once again: Read the official documentation. It includes a lot of hints about the usage of threads and explains resource handling in general and detail.

Comment: sir i'm having problem with this code now .. images which are loading in the gridView are mixing up on scrolling ... please tell me why this is happening and how can i stop this thing. P.S. desperately waiting for your reply here

Comment: @user1602152 you should check that your recycling of the views results in the correct loading of the bitmaps

Comment: @WarrenFaith i didn't get you .. how can i check recycling of views?

Comment: @user1602152 how about searching? You could stumble upon stuff like this: http://lucasr.org/2012/04/05/performance-tips-for-androids-listview/

Comment: @WarrenFaith sorry for replying late.. i was busy in something... and sir i have gone throw this also.. and i was still getting same issue and secondly he is using **AsyncTask.THREAD_POOL_EXECUTOR** which is only available from api level 11+ .. so is there any other possible way to overcome this issue? without changing my minimum sdk level?

Comment: They changed the working of AsyncTask a bit but you can create a simple API level switch to determine if you need the pool or not. If you still get the issue with the mixed up images, you should really start debugging the getView() method of your adapter to find out why the wrong image is loaded.

Comment: @WarrenFaith yeah i was debugging my getView() method and i have found a little thing that whenever i scroll the view, it start downloading pictures again? i dont know why?

Comment: Probably because you don't cache them? You should really search the web, there are tons of tutorials for lazy loading and caching for listviews. I will stop here...